# REACTJS: Changing variable value inside useEffect() ore accessing the error that appears in useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, use-effect, redux-toolkit

I am creating a submit-form and I am using useEffect() here.

useEffect receives a 400-Statuscode and an error message from my backend and I want to show that Error on my Submit-Form, but I am struggling to access this error outside the 'useEffect(()=>{}' - Scope.

this is my code (I am using `react-bootstrap` and `@redux-toolkid`):

Short version:

```
var error = null

useEffect(() => {
console.log('useEffect(): ')
console.log(createResult)
if (createResult.isSuccess) {
createResult.reset()
        dispatch(hideCreateMessageDialog())
    }
    if (createResult.error) {
        error = createResult.error


console.log(error) //output = null
```

I have also tried to use a `return(error)`statement, but that lets my whole application crash. I also tried to use `error` as parameter like `useEffect(error)()=>...`

**Why can't I access the error-variable within the useEffect()-scope??
I need to use the error-message in my JSX-Code**.

**How can I do this?**

value of `createResult.error`:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "data": {
        "Error": "Could not create forum message. Reason: Forum thread ID is missing"
    }
}
```

---

---

complete code bellow

---

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

// utils
import { jlog, jsn } from '../../../utils/parseJSON'
import JsonHelper from '../../../utils/parseJSON'

//bootstrap
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import FloatingLabel from 'react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner'
import Stack from 'react-bootstrap/Stack'

//redux
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// import selectors
import { selectCreateMessageDialog, selectHandleThreadID, selectHandleThreadName } from '../../../redux/ui/UISlices'

//import my reducers
import { useCreateMessageMutation } from '../../../redux/forum/ForumMessageSlice'
import { hideCreateMessageDialog } from '../../../redux/ui/UISlices'

export default function CreateMessageDialog() {
    var error = null
    const [createMessage, createResult] = useCreateMessageMutation()
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const parentThreadID = useSelector(selectHandleThreadID)
    const parentThreadName = useSelector(selectHandleThreadName)
    const handleSubmit = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const newMessage = {
            title: event.target.elements.ForumMessageTitleInput.value,
            text: event.target.elements.ForumMessageTextInput.value,
            threadID: parentThreadID
        }
        createMessage(newMessage)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect(): ')
        console.log(createResult)
        if (createResult.isSuccess) {
            createResult.reset()
            dispatch(hideCreateMessageDialog())
        }
        if (createResult.error) {
            error = createResult.error
            console.log('error in createResult: ')
            console.log(jsn(error))
            console.log(jsn(error.data.message))
            console.log(jsn(error.status))
        }
    })

    return (
        <>
            <Modal show={useSelector(selectCreateMessageDialog)} onHide={() => dispatch(hideCreateMessageDialog())}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>{JSON.stringify(error)}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <CreateMessageBody error={error} threadID={parentThreadID} threadName={parentThreadName} />
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button
                            variant='secondary'
                            id='CancelCreateForumMessageButton'
                            onClick={() => dispatch(hideCreateMessageDialog())}
                        >
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button type='submit' variant='primary' id='CreateForumMessageButton'>
                            Create Message
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Form>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}

function CreateMessageAlert({ error }) {
    return <JsonHelper data={error} />
    /* if (error) return error.data */
    return null
}

function CreateMessageBody(props) {
    console.log('props von CreateMessageBody: ' + jsn(props))
    if (false) {
        return (
            <Modal.Body>
                <Spinner animation='border' role='status'>
                    <span className='visually-hidden'>Loading...</span>
                </Spinner>
            </Modal.Body>
        )
    }

    

    return (
        <Modal.Body>
            <Stack>
                <JsonHelper data={props} />
                <CreateMessageAlert error={props} />
                <FloatingLabel controlId='ForumMessageTitleInput' label='Message Title' className='mb-3'>
                    <Form.Control type='text' name='ForumMessageTitleInput' placeholder='Eigener Title' />
                </FloatingLabel>

                <FloatingLabel controlId='ForumMessageTextInput' label='Message' className='mb-3'>
                    <Form.Control
                        as='textarea'
                        type='text'
                        name='ForumMessageTextInput'
                        placeholder='Message'
                        style={{ height: '125px' }}
                    />
                </FloatingLabel>
            </Stack>
        </Modal.Body>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll most likely looking to make the error a useState so your components can react to the changes.

your outside console.log(error) only runs once when the script loads

This is the documentation for useState

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

I’d start off with message being null and then display nothing if null
If message has something then display your message

Finally in your use effect set the state instead of the var